# How to declare a specific type of empty array inside a object using typescript?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

[image: code from the tutorial]

In the above code, I want to declare an empty Ingredient array instead of
`ingredients: [ new Ingredient('Apple', '5')]`

In the tutorial that I am doing, they don't show the case of the empty array. Is there a way to do it
or do I always have to declare some values to let the angular know the type of the array?

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the type of your state:

```
type State = {
  ingredients: Ingredient[];
}
```

and then set the type of `initialState` to `State`:

```
const initialState: State = {
  ingredients: [],
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should also work

```
    const initialState = {
      ingredients: new Array<Ingredient>()
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it really, try this:

```
let ingredients: Ingredient[] = [];
const initialState = {
    ingredients: ingredients
}
```

Not sure why you need to define it inside an object, but this will work.